# How to Separate Email and Phone NO from String

Tags: android, regression, extract

Intention : get the Email and Phone No from Image .

using following : https://v4all123.blogspot.com/2018/03/simple-example-of-ocrreader-in-android.html  I was able to get String from Image.

What remains is separate Email and Phone No from got string.

String Would be Dynamic base on selected business card.

example :  Kevin Reynolds
    CONNOLIY
    Passi
    on. Partnership. Performance.
    631.925.5523
    800.644.5268
    631.757.0021
    kevinr@@connollymusic.com
    vw.connollymusic.com
    Connolly Music Company | 8 Vernon Valley Rd | East Northport, NY 11731

While using @Sajith ans , not able to validate string . According to logic that correct ans but I can't pass validation method .

code :

```
Log.d("DataString",":"+textView.getText().toString());
                String DataString = textView.getText().toString();

                String[] splited = DataString.split("\\s+");


                for(int i =0 ; i < splited.length; i++) {
                    Log.d("splited",":"+splited[i]);

                    if(isValidMail(splited[i])){
                        Log.d("emailvalid","email valid condition ");
                        emailList.add(splited[i]);

                    }
                }
```

While Implementing above code isValidaMail contain follows :

```
private boolean isValidMail(String email) {
        boolean check;
        Pattern p;
        Matcher m;

        String EMAIL_STRING = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

        p = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_STRING);

        m = p.matcher(email);
        check = m.matches();

        if(!check) {

        }
        return check;
    }
```

I also tried :

```
private boolean isValidMail(String email) {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }
```

Comment: post your `String` here

Comment: @Sajith check updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all split your string by space and store them in a array.

```
str = "Hello I'm your String";
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
```

After that loop through the array to check whether the current string is matching to a format which represent email and telephone number. Use regular expressions for email and telephone number formats.

**EDIT**

use email validation like below

```
String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

public static   boolean  ValidateEmail(String email){

    if (email.matches(emailPattern)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: your ans was indeed helpful .